# Creating a form without submit action

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, forms

I'm trying to create a AcroForm using LaTeX. I also want to use `pdftk` to merge many PDFs. The problem is that `pdftk` does not behave well when it encounters it and the fields are hidden, as well as their value.

If I go in Acrobat and optimize the PDF, discarding form submission, import and reset actions, then all go well, even after being merged with pdftk.

My question is : is there a way to tell `hyperref` to not create form actions? Or is there a way to create fillable forms as easy as `hyperref`, and which do not create form actions.

Comment: As it stands, I don't think we'll get an answer here. At the very least we need some demo showing how you are setting up the forms.